# Converting Rows into Columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a row of data into columns, The code I am using below copies my selection but then past it several times over.

```
Sub Movefromrowtocolumn()
   Range("B3:P3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("Y2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
     :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Movefromrowtocolumn()
    Range("B3:P3").Copy
    Range("Y2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                             Operation:=xlNone, _
                             SkipBlanks:=False, _
                             Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

You needed to use `Transpose:=True`

Also [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Sub Movefromrowtocolumn()
Range("A1:E1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("F1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Maybe the transpose:=True instead of false like you had?